# Creating jpg thumb with php

Tags: php, image, gd, thumbnails

I am having problems creating a thumbnail from an uploaded image, my problem is

(i) the quality
(ii) the crop

http://welovethedesign.com.cluster.cwcs.co.uk/phpimages/large.jpg
http://welovethedesign.com.cluster.cwcs.co.uk/phpimages/thumb.jpg

If you look the quality is very poor and the crop is taken from the top and is not a resize of the original image although the dimesions mean it is in proportion.

The original is `1600px` wide by `1100px` high.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
 $thumb =
 $targetPath."Thumbs/".$fileName;

    $imgsize =
 getimagesize($targetFile);  $image =
 imagecreatefromjpeg($targetFile);
  $width = 200; //New width of image   
 $height = 138; //This maintains
 proportions

  $src_w = $imgsize[0]; $src_h =
 $imgsize[1];



 $thumbWidth = 200;  $thumbHeight =
 138; // Intended dimension of thumb

 // Beyond this point is simply code.

 $sourceImage =
 imagecreatefromjpeg($targetFile);
 $sourceWidth = imagesx($sourceImage);
 $sourceHeight = imagesy($sourceImage);

 $targetImage =
 imagecreate($thumbWidth,$thumbHeight);
 imagecopyresized($targetImage,$sourceImage,0,0,0,0,$thumbWidth,$thumbWidth,imagesx($sourceImage),imagesy($sourceImage));

 //imagejpeg($targetImage,
 "$thumbPath/$thumbName");
 imagejpeg($targetImage, $thumb);

 chmod($thumb, 0755);
```

Comment: for better quality use `imagecopyresampled()`: http://www.php.net/imagecopyresampled

Comment: Pretty much the same quality as before, I mainly do CF development now but I seem to remember a way of doing it that allows you to insert the quality

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way but the example code you pasted is a mess. You should try to remove the fluff and see if it solves some problem, at least if it doesn't it will make it easier for others to see the problem straight away.

Answer (score 1):

Every time u create a thumbnail the DPI of the image has to go low and thus it is not possible to have the same quality, however u can check imagecreatetruecolor (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php ) for improvement

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong variable for the image height.

```
imagecopyresized($targetImage,$sourceImage,0,0,0,0,$thumbWidth,$thumbWidth,imagesx($sourceImage),imagesy($sourceImage));
```

Should be:

```
imagecopyresized($targetImage,$sourceImage,0,0,0,0,$thumbWidth,$thumbHeight,imagesx($sourceImage),imagesy($sourceImage));
```

This should improve image quality but you should use imagecopyresampled for resizing and use the quality parameter when using the imagejpeg() function when saving to disk.

Comment: @Ross, if this answer solved your problem accept it as the correct answer

Comment: You may want to use `imagecopyresampled()` as well. resize is the 'low quality' version, if you're in a hurry and don't care about the quality of the resize. Resample is slower but does a better job.

Answer (score 0):

You would not worry if you would use the [Thumbnailer](http://freelogic.pl/thumbnailer).

```
$th=new Thumbnailer("your-photo.jpg");
$th->thumbSymmetricWidth(200)->save("your-thumb.jpg");
```

The quality is superb. You can also round the corners.